# Creating services. Extracting logic from views to separate files in pure React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example: My component has grown to a large size. Is it possible to create services in React? Download the data in the `services.js` file and update the status in the`index.js` file using React itself? I would like to separate some logic from views to separate files.

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-twgqsq

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import {getTodos} from './services';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getTodos();
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.todos)
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**services.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const  getTodos = () => {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';

    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url
    })
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        todos: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };
```

Comment: yes it's possible; for best results switch to hooks

Comment: @marzelin but I have to use class, not function. In class I can't use hooks

Comment: why do you have to use a class?

Comment: @marzelin Because I used pure react and I have a class. The component has about 2,000 lines and I need to reduce it. I need to move some logic to other files. If it was from scratch I would do as you say and use hooks.

Comment: then split the component into *container* and *presentational*

Comment: @marzelin It seems impossible to me. 1700 lines are logic itself :(

Comment: hooks were invented to help manage large components: https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#complex-components-become-hard-to-understand That's the best way to go

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible, but i will do something like this

service.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const  getTodos = async () => {
  let response;
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
    try{
      response = axios.get(url,{
        headers:{
          //Authorization if you have once
        }
      })
      response=JSON.stringify(response)
      return response
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }

};
```

react

```
import React, { Component,useEffect } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import {getTodos} from './services';


export const App = () =>{
  useEffect(()=>{
    getTodos().then(response => console.log(response))
  })

  return(<div></div>)

}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I am thinking more about something like that to use `this.setState` and update` this.state` in the constructor. And has to be class